# Calculated column to show number of items selected in a multichoice field

Tags: sharepoint

In SharePoint I have a table with a lookup column that takes in multiple values. I am having a problem finding a code for a calculated column that counts how many values the user chose. For example,

```
    Favorite Ice Cream
1   Vanilla; Chocolate; Strawberry

2  Cookies and Cream; Mint

3   Coconut; Chocolate; Butter Pecan; Strawberry
```

And an adjacent column will be...

```
    Number of total Ice Cream
1    3

2    2

3    4
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What did you tried to solve the problem? Do you get some numbers or is there any error message?

Comment: Please don't repeat tags in question titles.

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible with a calculated column. Maybe you'll have to use JavaScript into the NewForm and EditForm to save the number of selected values into the "Number of total Ice Cream" field...